# r - How can I remove a single pair of parentheses with text in a character?

Tags: r, gsub

I've got a character in R:

```
value <- "This is (delete) a (keep) test sentence."
```

I want to remove the first pair of parentheses with the text, but keep the second one. I tried to use a `gsub()`:

```
value2 <- gsub("(delete)", " ", value)
```

The result is: `"This is () a (keep) test sentence."`

But what I need is: `"This is a (keep) test sentence."`

What can I do to reach this?

Comment: You can try this `str_replace(value, "\\(.*?\\){1}", "")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sub` :

```
sub('\\(.*?\\)\\s', '', value)
#[1] "This is a (keep) test sentence."
```

- `()` are metacharacters and need to be escaped with `\\`.
- `.*?` is to match as few characters possible till a closing bracket (`)`) is encountered.

Comment: How about adding `\\s` to the pattern to remove 1 space away?

Comment: Good suggestion. Updated the answer.